# iPhone How to ignore Respect language direction

Tags: objective-c, settings, right-to-left, autocorrect

I have created an iPhone application with one UIViewController and designed it in storyboard. I've placed 3 UIImage each showing an image

[image]

- my phone system language interface is set to English (settings->general->international->language)

Changing my system language interface to Hebrew, running the application & the images appear in mirror mode (reverse order) like this

[image]

In the size inspector I've removed the checkmark of `Respect language direction` from all `Horizontal, Trailing & Leading constraints` but that didn't help.

What other ways are there to disable/ or ignore language interface automatic corrections?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @LenaBru I was pointed in the right direction

**The solution:** change all constraints that start with Horizontal, Trailing, Leading, Center  to left right instead of trailing & leading.

**Steps:**

1. open storyboard --> click on view controller --> click on control --> on the utilities panel go to the size inspector (ruler)
2. find the constraint (Horizontal, Trailing, Leading, Center) --> right click --> Select and Edit --> on second rule change from trailing leading to left right

**NOTE:** You have to go rule by rule doing so and unfortunately there no way to select all constraints and change together

**NOTE 2:** if you have a storyboard per language then life is easier go to the correct storyboard and perform step 1 & 2 and change the `direction` from `trailing leading` to `left right`. With this option you CAN select all constraints and change together

**Edit for xcode 6.0 and above:**
double click on the rule and remove the checkmark from `respect language direction` this will change the constraint from horizontal/leading/trailing/ center to left/right

Comment: I am also facing the same issue  and also change also change all trailing and leading constraints to left and right per still my view display as mirror.

Comment: Could you please provide screen shot for how to apply left right instead of leading-trailing.